# floating a list of strings

Tags: python, floating-point

I want to ask a question about converting strings into floats in python.

I have the following list:

```
coordinates_S
>>> ['0.00000000', '0.00000000', '0.10224900']
```

and I want to convert each item into a decimal using `float()`

Evidently, `float(coordinates_S` didn't work:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

which makes sense.

I tried this however:

```
flt_coordinates_S = []
    for item in coordinates_S:
        flt_coordinates_S += float(item)
```

i.e. iterating through each item in the list and it doesn't work. The error given is:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

but I can't seem to understand why. 
What am I doing wrong here?

I have not found a question that involves iterating items in a list *and* converting them to a float.

Comment: As an alternative, You could try `list(map(float, coordinates_S))`

Comment: In your second example, you're looking for [`list.append`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists). Using `+=` on a list is used for extending a list using another collection. You can also accomplish this via the list comprehension `[float(elem) for elem in coordinate_S]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you used `+=` (used for extending a list with the elements from another list) when you should have used `.append()` (used for adding a single element to a list). So that's why you get the error, because it thinks `float(item)` is a list because you've used `+=`.

```py
coordinates_S = ['0.00000000', '0.00000000', '0.10224900']
flt_coordinates_S = []
for item in coordinates_S:
    flt_coordinates_S.append(float(item))
```

Alternatively if you want to do it in one line:

```py
coordinates_S = ['0.00000000', '0.00000000', '0.10224900']
flt_coordinates_S = [float(item) for item in coordinates_S]
```

Comment: Minor nitpick on phrasing: `+=` does not "append a list to another list", it _extends_ a list from another iterable, i.e. appends each element in sequence.

Comment: Clarifiied the wording.

Answer (score 3):

`flt_coordinates_S += float(item)` is equivalent to `flt_coordinates_S.extend(float(item))`; `+=` extends a list with the contents of another iterable.

You want to *append* a `float` to the list.

```
flt_coordinates_S = []
for item in coordinates_S:
    flt_coordinates_S.append(float(item))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = ['0.00000000', '0.00000000', '0.10224900']
lst_float = [float(i) for i in lst]
print(lst_float)
[0.0, 0.0, 0.102249]
```

Try this. Issue with your code is +=. This works in case of string or numbers. Not to append elements to list

Answer (score 0):

You could use map to convert all the elements of the list directly into a new list

```
 flt_coordinates_S = list(map(float,coordinates_S))
```

Comment: You should generally prefer comprehensions over the use of `map`. They tend to read a lot better.